# How to turn the hot water off from the knob?

Tags: plumbing

How to turn the hot water off by the handle, on the bathroom sink?  The valve under the sink is stuck, and won't turn the water off. There is a hole in the pipe under the sink.

Comment: You will need to find another shut off that is before the struck one.  Maybe at the tank or the main water shut off valve.

Comment: You may want to use something like a "silicone rescue tape" to temporarily stop the pipe hole leaking and allow you to turn the upstream water back on while you arrange a repair.

Comment: force it close, if not by hand, use tools

Comment: If you force it, it may break. If it is a "multi turn" valve, once you shut off the upstream water, you may be able to disassemble the valve in place and fix it with a rebuild kit.

Comment: forcing will not break anything since it is not held open by other than some deposits or rust. but you could also call a plumber

Comment: Note for future reference that any multi-turn valve when opened should then be closed back a quarter turn. This prevents it from sticking open when you next need to use it, many years later. If you force it, you'll probably just break the handle or shaft. When you replace it, use a quarter-turn valve, they have far fewer issues over time.

Comment: Just watched a youtube about a shut off valve you can put on a pressurize water line without getting wet.  Was neat until they mentioned the 200 dollar price.

Answer (score 1):

Generally there should be a main shutoff to the whole house somewhere near where the water line enters the house. Then, in a well designed plumbing setup, there will be a shut off for each individual fixture so you can turn off the water to that individual fixture without shutting down the whole house.

Sometimes valves will get stuck after years (decades?) of non-use and won't function any more. If that's the case, you'll have to follow the plumbing from the sink back toward where your supply comes into the house to find another valve to turn off. It may end up being the main valve for the whole house. If you can't find that, you should be able to turn it off at the water meter using a "curb key" to turn the valve down in the meter box.

If you currently have a water leak and you can't find a functioning valve to turn the water off, I'd suggest calling the water company and asking them to send someone out for an emergency shut off or calling one or more local plumbers to find someone who can come immediately to do an emergency repair.

If you don't, you're going to continue to have water leaking in your house causing damage, and that will cost far more to repair than an emergency plumber's bill will cost you.

Comment: how about just call a plumber

Comment: That was one of the possibilities suggested, @Ruskes.